# Setting bareword environment variable not allowed while strict subs in use

Tags: perl, environment-variables, bareword

In order for my Perl script to run, I need to set an environment variable on the OS to point to our dev servers:

`export SERVER=DEV`

However, once the script is distributed to our users, I don't want them to need to export this environment variable each time. Therefore, I thought I would set the environment variable near the beginning of my script. So I added this:

`$ENV{SERVER}=DEV;`

However, my script won't allow this because of strict subs:

`Bareword "DEV" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`

I've been assured by my department supervisor we must use strict in our scripts, so there's no way of getting around that constraint. Is there a proper way to set bareword environment variables that I am overlooking?

Comment: "I've been assured by my department supervisor we must use strict in our scripts..." Finally, a **sane** manager!

Comment: How is the variable actually used in the script?

Comment: It appears to be used by a custom Perl module we use to access some DBs with department data we use in our scripts. The module seems to be built on top of DBD::Oracle, since that's what throws the error. We have a set of prod servers and dev servers. The schema I need is on the dev server, and not the prod. I guess which one you need was designed to be set in the OS.

Comment: Though if I look through the custom Perl module, I may be able to check where it's being used inside there.

Comment: So you get an error when you quote the value? Edit your question to include the exact error message and the block of code that's emitting it.

Comment: The error is that DBD::Oracle can't find the correct table, since it doesn't know where to look for it (ie. our dev servers). but looking at it now, it appears that the quotes were not actually the issue. I thought it wasn't finding the dev server because of the quotes, but commenting out use strict and then using the bareword DEV still does not find the correct server. Should I edit this question or would it be best to close it out?

Comment: I would edit the question to clarify that using quotes doesn't cause the script to fail. There's already a good answer explaining the issue with barewords that could be helpful to a future visitor, so I would leave the question open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment variables are strings.

You have many options to create the string `DEV` in bash. Primarily, you have

- `DEV`
- `"DEV"`
- `'DEV'`

You have many options to create the string `DEV` in Perl. Primarily, you have

- `"DEV"`, `qq{DEV}`
- `'DEV'`, `q{DEV}`

So,

```
$ENV{SERVER} = "DEV";
```